# How to load json data in java?

Tags: java, api, rest, testing, pojo

I'm quite new to API testing, I am wondering how to best and simple load some body?
I created simple pojo classes, but i am having problems with nested json.
ex:

```
{
    "listOfItems": [
        {
            "name": "name1",
            "value": "Jack"
        },
        {
            "name": "nameDate",
            "value": "20-08-2021-08-00-00"
        },
        {
            "name": "address",
            "value": "address here",
        }
        {
            "name": "name2",
            "value": "Smith"
        }
    ],
    "something": [],
    "size": 1
}
```

Then, in classes I used:

```
ClassName {
private List<ListOfItems> listOfItems;
private List<something> something;
private int size;

//setters and getters
}
```

and

```
Class ListOfItems{
private String name;
private String value;

//getters and setters
}
```

then in test class I am trying to use it, but have no idea how.

```
public Class Test {

 ClassName className = new ClassName();
ListOfItems list = new ListOfItems();
//how to get list with 3x name and 3x value like in json?

    className.setsize(150);

given().when().body(???).post("\endpoint").then()...

}
```

But I have no idea how to declare those 4 properties (name, value)

Comment: https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually on a pretty good track, you can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to help you out, [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F1d6ELxF1c) is the video example for your explanation which I used to learn Gson back when I needed it

Comment: Also not sure what IDE you are using but there is probably a plugin JSON to POJO, which can generate POJO just by pasting JSON to It